# Proof understanding: given unit vector $x$, find $y$, such that $y^* x = ||y|| = 1$

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

I was reading [this proof](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/pseudospectra/thms/thm1.pdf), section III $\to$ II, where the situation is as follows:

- a vector $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ is given, such that $||x|| = 1$, for some vector norm $||x||$.
- we are looking for a $y\in \mathbb{C}^n$, such that $y^*x = 1$ and $||y|| = 1$.

I can find $y$ if  $||\cdot|| = ||\cdot||_2$ or $||\cdot|| = ||\cdot||_\infty$, but I do not understand, how can $y$ exist in the case when $||\cdot|| = ||\cdot||_1$, since

$$|y^* x| = \left|\sum_{i} x_i \overline{y_i}\right|\leq
\sum_{i} |x_i \overline{y_i}|\leq\sum_i M_y |x_i| = M_y\text{,}$$
where $M_y = \max_i |y_i|$. Since $||y||_1 = 1$, we know that $M_y\leq1$. From the upper formula, it follows that we must have

- $M_y = 1$
- $|y_i| = M_y$, for all $i$,

otherwise $|y^* x| < 1$. Hence, $||y||_1 = \sum_i |y_i| = n$ and $y\neq 1$.

The proof says that *For general norms, the existence of such a
vector follows from the theory of dual norms (a corollary to the Hahn-Banach theorem).*

Comment: What's $y*x$? Inner product?

Comment: @5xum I assume so, because later on, some matrix $uw^*$ is defined, so I assumed that $w^* = \overline{w}^T$.

Comment: The $x$-norm and the $y$-norm must be [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Mathematical_Optimization). If you measure $x$ by $\|x\|_1$ then you should use $\|y\|_\infty$ and vice versa.

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_i M_y|x_i| = M_y$?

Comment: @JazzyMatrix Because $||x||_1 = \sum_i |x_i| = 1$

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you were still operating with an arbitrary norm.

Comment: @A.G. Well, (why) does it follow then that $E = xy^*$ has norm smaller or equal to $1$? Also, the proof says that the norm for $E$ is a matrix norm, induced from vector norm $||\cdot||$. Is there any theorem that guarantees that: if $||\cdot||_a$ and $||\cdot||_b$ are dual norms, then $||xy^*||_a\leq ||x||_a ||y||_b$ ?

Comment: @Antoine Because $u$ and $w$ are unit vectors and $\|uw^*v\|_a=|w^*v|\|u\|_a=|w^*v|\le\|w\|_b\cdot\|v\|_a\le 1$ for all unit vectors $v$.

Comment: @A.G. Thank you. Just to be sure: you have used Hölder's inequality in the last step?

Comment: @Antoine Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof from [Matrix Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521548233), by Johnson and Horn. It has a great chapter on norms, if you're curious.

> **Theorem 5.5.9 (Duality theorem)** [Let $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$]
>
> If $f$ is a norm, and $x_0\in V$ is given, then there is some $z\in V$ (not necessarily unique) such that $f^D(z)=1$ and $f(x_0)=z^*x_0$, that is, $|z^*x_0|\le f(x)$ for all $x\in V$ and $f(x_0)=z^*x_0$.

*Proof.*

For each given $x_0\in V$, [the equality of $f$ and $f^{DD}$] ensures that $f(x_0)=\max_{f^D(y)=1}\operatorname{Re}y^*x_0$, and compactness of the unit sphere of the norm $f^D$ ensures that there is some $z$ such that $f^D(z)=1$ and $\max_{f^D(y)=1}\operatorname{Re}y^*x_0=\operatorname{Re}z^*x_0$. If $z^*x_0$ were not real and nonnegative, there would be a real number $\theta$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(e^{-i\theta}z^*x_0)>0>\operatorname{Re}z^*x_0$ (of course, $f^D(e^{i\theta}z)=f^D(z)=1$), which would contradict maximality: $\operatorname{Re}z^*x_0\ge\operatorname{Re}y^*x_0$ for all $y$ in the unit sphere of $f^D$. $\qquad\qquad\Box$

Comment: Ok, so the existence is also proved:)